# Spring Boot GET Request gives 200 OK status, but Postman returns "ø" as response body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I'm brand new to Spring Boot, and I've been walking through this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtPkZShrvXQ), but I am stuck at this point. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I'm able to make a POST request and see the request go through with a 200 Status in Postman, but when I make a GET request to retrieve JSON data, I see a 200 Status, yet there is no response in Postman console, only a "ø" - anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Here is my Controller:

```
package com.example.demo.api;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import com.example.demo.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@RequestMapping("/api/v1/person")
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    //reference to the service
    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    //POST
    @PostMapping
    public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        personService.addPerson(person);
    }

    //GET
    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> getAllPeople() {
        return personService.getAllPeople();
    }
}
```

Here is the service file:

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.dao.PersonDao;
import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonDao personDao;

    @Autowired
    public PersonService(@Qualifier("fakeDao") PersonDao personDao) {
        this.personDao = personDao;
    }

    public int addPerson(Person person) {
        return personDao.insertPerson(person);
    }

    public List<Person> getAllPeople() {
        return personDao.selectAllPeople();
    }

    public Optional<Person> getPersonById(UUID id){
        return personDao.selectPersonById(id);
    }
}
```

And here is the interface:

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

//insert person into database
public interface PersonDao {

    //this inserts a person with an id
    int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person);

    //this inserts a person that does not have an id. An idea is generated:
    default int insertPerson(Person person) {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        return insertPerson(id, person);
    }

    List<Person> selectAllPeople();

    Optional<Person> selectPersonById(UUID id);

    int deletePersonById(UUID id);

    int updatePersonById(UUID id, Person person);
}
```

Comment: By the way, if you're using JPA, Spring Data JPA will auto-generate your DAO implementation for you and can provide useful help like allowing you to say `@GetMapping("/{id}")... @PathVariable("id") Person person`. Additionally, it's usually a good idea to separate out a DTO class (`PersonDto`) from your database representation so that you can make changes to either as needed without breaking anything. MapStruct is a tool that can help you with conversions to and from DTO representations.

Comment: Can you please clarify your second paragraph? Which request is returning the empty body?

Comment: The GET request is returning the empty body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops - there was a typo in my Data Access Service File. I don't know how I had the selectAllPeople() method returning "null" instead of the database (DB), but that's what I had:

```
    @Override
    public List<Person> selectAllPeople() {
        return null;
    }
```

And the amazing solution, lol:

```
    @Override
    public List<Person> selectAllPeople() {
        return DB;
    }
```

Thanks for the feedback and the patience, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns 200 (because it returns successfully and doesn't specify any other status code), but it returns an empty body because it's `void` and doesn't use any other mechanism to return content.

If you like, you can return a DTO object from the method, and whether you do or not you should return `ResponseEntity.created(uri)` to provide the `Location` header. `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` can be helpful in constructing a URI for the new resource.

Comment: Looks to me like they're saying they're GET returns the empty body.

Comment: @Savior I think you're right and I misread. In that case, we'd need more detail.